# How to detect audio folders in flutter like MX Player does?

Tags: flutter, android-mediaplayer, audio-player

Recently I started working on an **Audio Player flutter project**. And as a flutter beginner, I had to search for things needed to fulfill the project. **I wanted a media folder detection mechanism like the MX Player app does.**
But after searching the whole day on the web for it, I didn't find anything useful.

*Please suggest to me how to achieve this functionality or are there any packages available for that?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a file scan and filter files found by their extensions (mp3,aac...) to get your audio files.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That should do the job. But still, it's not fulfilling my actual requirement. I wanted to show audio files along with their parent folders. For example, the MainPage will show the list of folders containing audio files.

Comment: For your main page, you can scan every folder and only show it when it has an audio file in it. When clicking on the folder for example, you will show a list of audio files (and other folders inside of it if there is).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ContentResolver` query like

```
`Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%utm%"}, null)`
```

Example is shown [here](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/23916/fetch-audio-mp3-files-from-specific-folder-of-device-or-fetch-all-files)

Comment: This way is useful for android java, but this issue is not for flutter.